# Add <th> text on the each <td> - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I want to show my tabular data into different rows in mobile layout. So what i am trying to do is to add  values in each :before pseudo-selector. so it should display like that.

Name: xyz

Age:  20

Name: abc

Age:  30

Please see my JQuery code here. It is working fine if there is only one  but if there are multiple  then it doesn't work

JQuery:

```
if ($('table').length) {
    var th_data;
    $('table th').each(function (index) {
        var index_th = index;
        th_data = $(this).text();
        $('table td').each(function (index) {
            var index_td = index;
            if (index_th == index_td) {
                $(this).attr('data-content', th_data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

CSS code:

```
table th{display:none;}
table td:before{content:attr(data-content) '';position:absolute;top:6px;left:6px;width:45%;padding-right:10px;white-space:nowrap;}
table td{position:relative;padding-left:50%;display:block;}
```

Solution:

I think I have figured it out. so the updated JQuery code is this. And it is working fine on multiple

```
 /* Changing the tabular data into rows */
if ($('table').length) {
    var th_data;
    $('table').each(function () {
        var _table = $(this);
        $(this).find('th').each(function (index) {
            var index_th = index;
            th_data = $(this).text();
            _table.find('tr').each(function () {
                $(this).find('td').each(function (index) {
                    var index_td = index;
                    if (index_th == index_td) {
                        $(this).attr('data-content', th_data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

two places $(this) are not the same. So save it as a variable. Try this, hope can help a bit

```
if ($('table').length) {
    var th_data;
    $('table th').each(function (index) {
        var index_th = index;
        var th = $(this);
        th_data = $(th).text();
        $('table td').each(function (index) {
            var index_td = index;
            if (index_th == index_td) {
                var td = $(this);
                $(td).attr('data-content', th_data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
if ($('table').length) {
    var th_data = new Array(),
        temp = '';
    $('table th').each(function (index) {
        th_data[index] = $(this).text();
    });
    $('table tr').each(function (index) {
        var tr = $(this);
        $(this).find('td').each(function(index){
            temp+= th_data[index]+':'+$(this).text()+'<br />';
        });
        temp+= '<br />';
    });
    $('.result').append(temp);
}
```

```css
table td{
border: 1px solid #000;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="header">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="result"><Br /><br /><b>Output:</b><br /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the original code is that the selector `$('table td')` gets all the `<td>` elements in all the rows.

Instead, for each `<th>` element, loop through the body rows and use the `.eq()` function to get the correct `<td>` in the row.

```
$('table').each(function() {
    var $table = $(this);
        $rows = $table.children('tbody').children();
    $table.children('thead').children().children().each(function(i) {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $rows.each(function() {
            $(this).children().eq(i).attr('data-content', text);
        });
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zsxumcr/1/)